# data frame for fitting "Actual vs predicted" in BSTS package

Tags: r, time-series, bayesian

I am trying to run a Bayesian structural time series for my time-series data.  But stuck on with data frame this error. I'm an active learner of R and new to time series modelling. Please anyone can help me in fixing the following error? Thank you in advance.
I adopted the codes from (https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2016/04/21/forget-arima/)
The Arima model runs and the results are satisfactory. But I am struck with the data frame of Bayesian structural time series model.
**Note: The actual "AirPassengers" data is 12 years. Whereas, mine is a 10 years monthly time series data.**

## The BSTS model

```
'

ss <- AddLocalLinearTrend(list(), y)
    ss <- AddSeasonal(ss, y, nseasons = 12)
    bsts.model <- bsts(y, state.specification = ss, niter = 500, ping=0,  seed=2018)
```

'

## Get a suggested number of burn-ins

```
burn <- SuggestBurn(0.1, bsts.model)
```

## Predict

```
p <- predict.bsts(bsts.model, horizon = 24, burn = burn, quantiles = c(.025, .975))
p
plot(p)
```

## But I am struck with the data frame.

```
d2 <- data.frame(
c(10^as.numeric(-colMeans(bsts.model$one.step.prediction.errors[-(1:burn),])+y),  
10^as.numeric(p$mean)), 
as.numeric(IPTS),
as.Date(time(IPTS)))
```

## I am getting an error message:

```
Error in data.frame(c(10^as.numeric(-    colMeans(bsts.model$one.step.prediction.errors[-(1:burn),  : arguments imply   differing number of rows: 144, 120
```

I want to plot the BSTS -- Holdout MAPE for my timeseries data.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Try check the dims of your objects (e.g., `y, bsts.model$one.step.prediction.errors, p$mean`, etc.) and make sure they are the sizes you expect.